# odd non linear system (simple)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the system
$x^{'} = x(x^{2} + y^{2})$, $y^{'} =y(x^{2} + y^{2})$

Questio part 1) find the equilibrium of the point system and describe its behavior.
when i do this i just get the zero matrix which corresponding to nothing moving ever so clearly the liearization is a poor description at the fixed point but i need to explain why?

going to polar r^{'}r= $r^{4} (\cos^{2} \theta + \sin^{2} \theta)$ thus $r^{'}=r^{3}$

and $\theta^{'}=0$ thus $\theta$ is a constant i thik this just corresponds to circles depending on the initial values what u guys think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linearization predicts that the origin is a center, but does not provide more details.

Your analysis with polar coordinates is correct.

$\theta^{'}=0$ leads to a constant angle.

If we plot the phase portrait (make sure to pay attention to the direction fields)!

[image]

What do you notice from this picture? Does it validate your linearization results?

Comment: no my linearization implies that nothing will move in any direction this shows that everything will away from the fixed point with a sent constant angle

Comment: @BabakS.: Thank you my friend! You might like this one too http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342100/nonlinear-phase-portrait-and-linearization/342327#342327

Comment: @Faust7: Your comment is correct. The reason is that Linearization only works (mostly) as long as the fixed point for the linearized system is not one of the borderline cases. Regards

Comment: That's awesome! +1